# Change back to the default background color in DefaultTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am reading the following section:

- [How to Use Tables - Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

So I decided to write my own custom renderer:

```
public class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    protected void setValue(Object value) {
        try {
            String text = MyFormatter.format(value);
            //setBackground(Color.white); // my text becomes invisible
            //setBackground(null); // my text becomes invisible
            setBackground(???);
            setText(text);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // Something is not quite right, indicate the error to the user:
            setBackground(Color.red); // at this point in time getBackground() returns Color.blue
            super.setValue(value);
        }
    }
}
```

I understood how to change the background color to indicate a field with an error in the format. After manual editing by the user, I'd like to have the field reverted back to the original background color. But so far I did not understood how to do it. Can I use [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html) in this case ? Should I implement [`TableCellRenderer .getTableCellRendererComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) instead ?

I was able to get something to display with:

```
            [...]
            String text = MyFormatter.format(value);
            setBackground(null);
            setForeground(null); // need both to null
            setText(text);
```

but this breaks the video inverse mode when selecting the row...

---

Update: I cannot use `getBackground()` and store the color value in a private member since when editing the background color is `Color.blue`.

Comment: `setBackground(null);` *should* work

Comment: I'm not understanding the question. Couldn't you maintain a reference to the initial color (use `getBackground()` before changing, to keep a reference) then use that reference anytime you need to revert the color back to its original?

Comment: Again `setBackground(null);` *should* work. If it's not working, then please post your [mcve] program code so we can test your code for ourselves.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but *again* what we need is a MCVE. Else I'm afraid all we can do is commiserate with you. Please read the link.

Comment: Just reiterating: Please edit in a MCVE, or you may not get the help you desire. @HovercraftFullOfEels, wouldnt `setBackground(null)` set the background to the parent's color, opposed to the component's initial/original color? "*if this parameter is null, then this component will inherit the background color of its parent*" (from `Component#setBackground`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much trial-and-errors, here is the only solution I found so far:

```
protected void setValue(Object value) {
    try {
        String text = MyFormatter.format(value);            
        if (errorState) {
            updateUI(); // call setBackground(null) and properly repaint()
            errorState = false;
        }
        setText(text);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // store error state:
        errorState = true;
        // Something is not quite right, indicate the error to the user:
        setBackground(Color.red);
        super.setValue(value);
    }
}
```

This is not perfect since the background is displayed as *white* instead of *blue* after editing is done. But that's better than the original behavior where the text would not appear after editing is done.